# What to do when a question is deleted by the author before I can post my answer?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I had just prepared some nice images (see below) to answer [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/80350/is-it-true-that-the-width-of-the-upper-deck-of-the-747-8i-is-the-same-as-the-wid). But before I could post an answer, the author of the question deleted it. For reference, this was the question:

> **Is it true that the width of the upper deck of the 747-8i is the same as the width of the cabin of the 737?**
>
> Lufthansa, Air China, Korean Air is the current passenger operator of the B747-8i. I'm curious about the width of the upper deck since the width of the B747-8i is similar to the B737-700.

What should I do about this now? The way I see it, there are three options:

1. Vote to **undelete** the question against the author's wish.
2. Post my **own question** with similar (or possibly equal?) content and then self-answer it.
3. Just let it go...

---

For those who care, nice images based on the [Boeing Airport Planning Documents](https://www.boeing.com/commercial/airports/plan_manuals.page):

[image: 747-8 Dimensions]
[image: Combination]

Comment: I don't have a definitive/authoritative answer. Personally, even though I know it's difficult, I would go with 3.

Answer (score 4):

If you've put a lot of effort into the answer, it's non-trivial, and likely to benefit the community **beyond answering the OP's curiosity**, I'd go with option 2.

In this particular case, the answer is useful and nicely illustrates the comparison, but probably not quite to the point of being "something to write home about" for aviation enthusiasts - the threshold I'd consider for calling for a self-answered question.

It's definitely up to you (or any other user). You don't have anything to lose, except perhaps looking a little silly for asking and answering an easy question.